# Is this black and red speedboat model from an official set or a MOC?

Tags: set-identification, moc

[image]

Please help me: is this from an official set or an MOC?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is part of [6679-1: Dark Shark](https://brickset.com/sets/6679-1/Dark-Shark)

[image]

Comment: perfect, thanx Syberion!